# How do i configure nginx to do image filtering?

Tags: nginx

I'm making my own image server and i'm trying to get the nginx **HttpImageFilterModule** to work.

basically i want it so that:

- `http://images.example.com/original/path/to/image` will get the original image
- `http://images.example.com/filter/path/to/image` will apply the named filter

How should I set up my server block in the nginx config to achieve this?

My current config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  images.example.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location /orignal/ {
        root   /var/www/;
    }

    location /img/ {
        root   /var/www/;
        image_filter   resize  150 100;
        error_page     415   = /50x.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it have documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: it does, and i understand that if i want to resize something i just add 
    'image_filter   resize  150 100;' into the location block but i'm having trouble with the /original/ and /filter/ routing.

doc:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpImageFilterModule

Comment: First thing: You misspelled `original` in the config. Second: You say you want `/filter` as a path component for the filtered images, but you name it `/img` in the config file. Both might be errors in your post only, or they might be the source of your issues.

Comment: well i had meant for filter to be a generic place holder, so that's my bad for not communicating that.  it turns out however that the nginx i had installed didn't have the image module configured, but no error was thrown when i reloaded nginx.  it wasn't until i did an nginx stop and start that an error was thrown.

Comment: the last problem is that i needed to use alias instead of root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Moving solution from [OP comment](https://serverfault.com/users/200045/derick-f) to answer box</sub>

It turns out however that the nginx I had installed didn't have the **HttpImageFilterModule** configured. Unfortunately no error was thrown when I reloaded nginx. It wasn't thrown until I did an `nginx stop` and `nginx start`

The last problem is that I needed to use `alias` directive instead of `root`.